# Curve fitting form selection/suggestions

Tags: plot, scipy, curve-fitting

My question is a very simple one. But I am confused as to the form I should select to fit data. I am using scipy.optimize for the fitting. I have data of the form shown in figure:

[image]

Which is the best form to fit such data? (For e.g. parabolic, polynomial, hyperbolic, power etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try hyperbolic x^(-n)+c or logarithmic a*ln(x).

Usually, you get a good guess for the proper fitting function when you consider where your data came from.
Also think about the limits of 0 and infinity. Think about what your data *should* do qualitatively when it approaches these limits (e.g. will it go to +/- infinity? will it approach a fixed value, etc.), and select your fitting function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to fit by a polynomial if you are unsure of the nature of your data. Otherwise, one can plot the quantities below, and if any of them yield a straight line, that would be the best form for this fit,

- `1/y(x)` on a linear scale:  hyperbolic function
- `y(x)` on a `log-log` scale : power law
- `y(x)` on a `semilogx` scale: logarithmic function